# Using Ascii characters to count characters

Tags: c, count, ascii

Why does the code I commented out does not work to count the digits 0-9?
for example when the input is happy 34567 fans#. The number counter should be 5 and letter counter should be 9.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    /*edit*/
   /* Write your code here */
   char ch;
   int letter_counter=0, num_counter=0;
   printf("Enter your characters (# to end):\n");
   while((ch = getchar()) != '#'){
       //if( ('A'<=ch<='Z') || ('a'<= ch <= 'z')){
       if ((ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')  ||  (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')){
           letter_counter++;
       }
       //else if('0' <=ch <= '9'){
       else if(ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') {
           num_counter++;
       }
   }
   printf("The number of digits: %d\n", num_counter);
   printf("The number of letters: %d", letter_counter);


    /*end_edit*/
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is better to use `isalpha()` and `isdigit()`.

Comment: Because the language says so. `'a' <= ch <= 'z'` will do the double comparison in Python but not in C. Each language has its precise semantics...

Comment: The comparison `'A'<=ch<='Z'` doesn't do what you want.  It's equivalent to `('A'<=ch)<='Z'`.  I.e., it compares `'A'` with `ch`, obtaining a `0` or `1` result, then compares that result with `'Z'`.  So the comparison will always be true.  Change it to `'A'<=ch && ch<='Z'`, and similarly for the other comparisons.

Comment: I noticed that you have not upvoted several of the answers that you have accepted. Note that you now have more than 15 reputation, so you have gained the [upvote priviledge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up). Therefore, you may want to consider upvoting any answers that you accept, as well as any other answers that you may find useful. Accepting an answer and upvoting an answer are two separate actions. You can only accept one answer per question, but this limit does not apply to upvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expressions

`'0' <=ch <= '9'`

and

`'A' <= ch <= 'Z'`

and

`'a' <= ch <= 'z'`

will all evaluate to true, irrespective of the value of `ch`.

According to the [rules of operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), the expression

`'A' <= ch <= 'Z'`

is equivalent to:

`('A'<=ch) <= 'Z'`

The sub-expression `'A'<=ch` will evaluate to either true (`1`) or false (`0`), so the entire expression will be equivalent to either

`0 <= 'Z'`

or:

`1 <= 'Z'`

Assuming that you are using an ASCII-compatible character set, `'Z'` will have the character code `90`, so the entire expression will be equivalent to either

`0 <= 90`

or:

`1 <= 90`

In both cases, the expression will evaluate to true.

That is why you must write

`ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'`

or

`'A' <= ch && ch <= 'Z'`

instead of:

`'A' <= ch <= 'Z'`

Also, it is worth noting that you can simplify your code a bit, by using the functions [isalpha](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) and [isdigit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isdigit). Both of these functions require you to `#include <ctype.h>`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() 
{
   int ch;
   int letter_counter=0, digit_counter=0;

   printf( "Enter your characters (# to end):\n" );
   while ( (ch=getchar()) != '#') {
       
       if ( isalpha( ch ) ) {
           letter_counter++;
       }
       else if ( isdigit( ch ) ) {
           digit_counter++;
       }
   }

   printf( "The number of digits: %d\n", digit_counter);
   printf( "The number of letters: %d\n", letter_counter);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do it like that :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
   char ch;
   int letter_counter=0, num_counter=0;

   printf("Enter your characters (# to end):\n");
   while((ch = getchar()) != '#'){
       if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
           letter_counter += 1;
       if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
           letter_counter += 1;
       if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
           num_counter += 1;
   }
   printf("The number of digits: %d\n", num_counter);
   printf("The number of letters: %d", letter_counter);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any advantage in this solution, except that it maybe looks a bit nicer. The disadvantages are: 1. Code duplication, and 2. introducing unnecessary checks by removing the `else`.

Comment: yours is indeed better

Comment: i didn't knew if he could use functions

Comment: I wasn't comparing your code to my code, but rather to OP's original code. The fact that you are duplicating the line `letter_counter += 1;` is not that bad, because it is only one line of unnecessary code duplication, but the fact that you have removed the `else` makes your code significantly worse in my opinion, as it introduces unnecessary checks. The program now checks if the input is a digit, even when it already knows it's a letter. Therefore, you may want to consider putting the `else` back in. Why did you remove it in the first place? Is it because the code looks better that way?

Comment: yep for smaller code i prefer it clear and it won't really cause any trouble

Comment: Would maybe [this solution](https://pastebin.com/w290beF1) be acceptable to you, in which the 3 conditions are aligned nicely?

Comment: yeah it looks nice ! ty